# SQL - How can I get the quantity of parts from this query and still have all the notes associated with these requests?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
Select p.Description
     , cast(floor(cast(f.CreatedDate as float)) as datetime) as RequestDate
     , Sum(f.Quantity) as QuantityOfParts
     , Coalesce(n.Note + ' / ','') as Notes
  from FulfillmentLine f 
  join Part p 
    on p.PartGUID = f.PartGUID
  left 
  join Note n 
    on n.ParentGUID = f.FulfillmentLineGUID
 where cast(floor(cast(f.CreatedDate as float)) as datetime) between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-19'
 Group 
    by p.Description
     , cast(floor(cast(f.CreatedDate as float)) as datetime)
     , Coalesce(n.Note + ' / ','')
 order 
    by cast(floor(cast(f.CreatedDate as float)) as datetime)
```

In this query I am checking our database for all fufillment requests in a certain date range based on part requested and date requested. The not table is linked to the request in its own table and has any important notes about the request. An example would be if the item is not in our database but still can be ordered. What I want is that even if a part is requested multiple times in one day I want that total quantity in one row. The problem is that if there is more than one note then a row is created for each note. Is there a way to change my query so that all the notes for the parts are listed in one row.

Example:

What I have now:

```
See Note |  2015-02-01 | 5 | Pads of paper/ 
See Note |  2015-02-01 | 7 | Syringes/ 
See Note |  2015-02-01 | 2 | Packs of pens/
```

What I want:

```
See Note |  2015-02-01 | 14 | Pads of paper/ Syringes/ Packs of Pens
```

Comment: Is the query expected to run on both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: To be completely honest I am not sure. I run this on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but I have been told that we are using MySQL. My knowledge of SQL has unfortunately only been very basic and I do not know the difference between the different SQL's besides knowing that there is some.

Comment: `SELECT description, requestdate, SUM(quantityofparts) total,GROUP_CONCAT(notes SEPARATOR '/') notes FROM (your query) x GROUP BY description,requestdate;`

Comment: @DonnieShannon, if you want to write as portable SQL as possible, try to follow ANSI SQL syntax. Some tricky areas are date/time, stored procedures, triggers, cast/convert, where too many products don't follow the standard. A great timesaver is the SQL Validator, to verify ANSI SQL syntax (just syntax): http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT name, date, count(column), GROUP_CONCAT(`field` separator ',') as `myfield`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name, date
```

Comment: The GROUP_CONCAT() function is not a recognized function according to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I assume this means that the function is from a different version of SQL?

Comment: Are you not using mysql? You are using SQL Server then?

Comment: Also for future reference, what is a good way to find out what SQL version I am using?

Comment: I told the guy above this as well. I am inexperienced when it comes to SQL. The job has just kind of thrown me into the role. So my knowledge is lacking in many areas. So I am not actually sure which SQL we use here and am currently unsure as to how to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server, the Stuff function would work for you.

[Here is an example for you to review](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function)

Comment: I am having issues using the stuff function. In the original query I have replaced the coalesce function with STUFF( (Select Note from Note where note.ParentGUID = f.FulfillmentLineGUID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) but I am getting an error saying 'FulfillmentLine.FulfillmentLineGUID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause and am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Paste your query in and let's see what is being aggregated. More than likely you will need to drop all of this query into a sub-select, CTE, or Temp table first before you Sum your Quantity